# Assume $a,b \in \mathbb{P}$, Why $2^1 a^7 b^5$ has equal number of even and odd-factors?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

> $a$ and $b$ are prime numbers greater than 2.

Quantity A: The number of even factors of $2^1 a^7 b^5$

Quantity B :The number of odd factors of $2^1 a^7 b^5$

---

The answer says Quantity A equals Quantity B.

---

I think the only prime number that is even is two.
Since this is a comparison, we may divide both Quantity A and Quantity B by two.

I think Quantity A after division by two has no even factors.
I think all the factors of quantity B are odd.

Why is my reasoning incorrect?

Comment: You can set up a one-to-one correspondence between the even factors and the odd factors. $d$ is an odd factor if and only if $2d$ is an even factor.

Comment: When can't you setup an injective correspondence between even and odd-factors in a number? @GerryMyerson

Comment: When the number is odd. When the number is a multiple of four.

Comment: If the number is of the form $2^1a^{n}b^m$, there are in total $(1+1)(n+1)(m+1)$ factors. The even factors are of the form $2a^rb^s$ where $0\le r\le n$ and $0\le s\le m$ and the odd factors are $a^rb^s$ where $r$ and $s$ are the same precedent. It follows that $$\text{ number of factors of } (2a^rb^s+a^rb^s)=(n+1)(m+1)+(n+1)(m+1)=2(n+1)(m+1)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each factor $f$ in the set of factors of $a^7b^5, f$ is an odd factor of $2a^7b^5$ and $2f$ is an even factor of $2a^7b^5.$

A number with prime factor decomposition $p_1^ip_2^jp_3^k$ will have $(i+1)(j+1)(k+1)$ factors.

$2^1a^7b^5$ has $(1+1)(5+1)(7+1) = 96$ factors.